# Removing certain elements of an array based on another array (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have arrays

```
A = [7 4 6 1 2 3 5]
B = [1 5 4 0 0 2 0]
```

(Array `A` will always have `length=7` with the numbers in a random order.)

I want to keep the order of A, but only retain the values if its corresponding index of `B` is `>0`.

So from the example above, I'd want to change `A` to `[6 1 2 3]`. Meaning, the 7th, 4th, and 5th elements in B equal 0, so delete values 7, 4, and 5 from `A`.

I'd like to do this without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A(B(A)>0)

or:

> A(find(B(A)))

though I believe the latter is less efficient

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It looks like the OP means A will always be randperm(7) so this answer is correct